# HTML - Placing Controls on Top of Eachother

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, controls

I am trying to figure out how to place controls on top of one another in html.

For example. I am trying to place 2 labels on top of eachother. and also I am trying to place a text box under a dropdownList.

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use css position to do that

Comment: ooooh okay I didn't think a bout that

Answer (score 1):

Set your elements to `position:absolute` (within a container that is set to `position:relative`). Then set the `z-index` of the elements that are supposed to be beneath other elements to a lower integer value. For example, within the container, an absolutely-positioned element with a z-index of 1 will display beneath one that has a z-index of 2. Note that there is a natural z-index that takes place within the document flow: elements that appear in the markup *before* other elements will go below the later elements, all things equal.

Answer (score 0):

using css is the correct choice, but if you only need to position your controls, you can create a table and place them in the table's cells the way you like.